# Syntax Error in Octave plotting

Tags: plot, fft, octave

I got the following syntax error while I want to plot values:

```
       syntax error

>>> plot(freq1, abs(fft1/max(fft1)),xlabel('f(Hz)'), ylabel('Amplitude I(f)');
                                                                             ^
```

My definitions are as follows:

```
a=x+y+z; % a is a sinus mixture of different curves/functions 
n1 = fa/0.05; % N is 50 ms
fft1=fft(a,n1);
freq1 = [0:deltaF1:fa-fft1];
plot(freq1, abs(fft1/max(fft1)),xlabel('f(Hz)'), ylabel('Amplitude I(f)');
```

EDIT: It would be nice stop voting me down, I know that question is not too interesting (please see below in the comment to the answer), thank you!

Comment: 1. You haven't actually posted the error.  2. Matlab helpfully puts a little red line next to the line where you have the error. 3. Count parentheses

Comment: you are missing a `)` at the end of the `plot` command, but the error message should be clear "Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket."

Comment: @m.s. you are right. After I corrected the missing paranthesis the syntax error vanished.

Comment: @DaveDurbin I did not post the syntax error because it did not show the exact position and it was a trivial error message so far...

Comment: @DaveDurbin I added the error message. As you can see the error log is not shown exactly as it states only the semicolon and not the missing parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more opening brackets `(` than closing ones `)`, that's a syntax error.

It should be:

```
plot(freq1, abs(fft1/max(fft1)),xlabel('f(Hz)'), ylabel('Amplitude I(f)'));
```

Comment: Yes, as the other users has already commented, thank you. I apologize for being to fast posting this question as it may be not so interesting for other users.